# VS2010 website debugger in wrong VS instance

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

we currently have 2 developers working on 2 different websites, on the same server.

when an error occurs in one of the web applications, that debug option pops up for the wrong developer. how do we specify what VS instance is to be used for which w3wp debugger process attached?

Comment: Are both developers logged into the same server, each running Visual Studio in their remote desktop session?

Comment: correct.... this is the set up for now

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of options sorted from best to worst...

1. Run Visual Studio locally on the developer's computers so this isn't a problem.
2. On the server, use Visual Studio's web server instead of IIS.  This gives each user an automatically created local process that can be debugged.
3. If you must use IIS, configure each application in IIS so that they run in their own application pools.  Each application pool gets its own w3wp process so your Visual Studio instances can attach to their own process.